# Show / Hide using mouseover and jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this block of code. The idea is, that when I `mouseover` `li#anchor`, previously hidden `ul#seeMore` should show up.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("li#anchor").mouseenter(function() {
        jQuery('ul#seeMore').css("display","block");
    });

    jQuery("li#anchor").mouseleave(function() {
        setTimeout( function(){
            jQuery('ul#seeMore').css("display","none");              
        },1000);
    });
})
```

The problem is that I also want that the second `mouseleave` function should not happen if I am still hovering the `ul#seeMore`

Or, probably the question should be: How can I ascertain if I'm not hovering the `ul#seeMore`?

I tried to change `jQuery("li#anchor").mouseleave(function() {` to `jQuery("ul#seeMore").mouseleave(function() {` but it seems this is not very stable.

Comment: I did that renato, still I'm loosing the ul even if I'm hovering that. The other problem is that I'm not able to position ul#seeMore above other neighboring divs.

Comment: Can you show us the html code? How the ul/li elements are constructed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `ul#seemore` inside `li#anchor` element. This way, when the mouse is up `ul#seemore`, it will be up the `li#anchor` element

Comment: well, actually it solved my issue. Do you have a solution to my other problem; like positioning the ul above other elements? z-index is not working.

Comment: You are actually right Renato, the z-index is working, I probably screwed things up somewhere else.

Comment: @Jeremy Very nice! Good luck to find out what is screwed! :)